# Anchor in nodes near coords is not working

Tags: tikz-pgf, anchor

In order to plot negative percentages under de bar en positive above de bar. I used the anchor argument, and used the dependence on visualization for each coord. However, my anchor is not working because it ignores the sign(\myy).

Can you help me to get it work?

```
 \usepackage{pgfplots}
 \usepackage{tikz}
 \usepackage{subcaption}
 \usepackage{graphicx}
 \usepackage{calculator}

\usepackage{xfp,xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\int_new:N\l_bjprim_round_int
\keys_define:nn {bjprim}
{
 positions-after-comma .int_set:N = \l_bjprim_round_int
 }

 \NewDocumentCommand\percentage { O{} m }
 {
 \keys_set:nn {bjprim}{positions-after-comma=2,#1}
\fpeval{round(#2*100,\l_bjprim_round_int)}\%
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{figure}[h]

 \centering


 \begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[
 ybar,
 enlargelimits=1,
 legend style={at={(0.5,-0.15)},
  anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
ylabel={Rendement op geïnvesteerd vermogen},
 yticklabel ={\pgfmathparse{\tick*100}\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}\,\%},
  symbolic x coords={Vorig jaar,Huidig jaar},
 xtick=data,
point meta = explicit symbolic ,
  visualization depends on=y \as \myy,
nodes near coords,
  node near coord style = {anchor ={\sign(\myy)*90}},
 bar width = 1.5cm,
 ymajorgrids =true,
 ]
 \addplot[fill,color=red] 
 coordinates{(Vorig jaar,0.05)[\percentage{0.05}] (Huidig jaar,-0.05) 
[\percentage{-0.05}]};



  \end{axis}
 \end{tikzpicture}


 \end{figure}
```

[image]

Comment: Please provide a complete example, which begins with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}`, so that others can copy, paste, and compile your example conveniently.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sign` directly. If you prefer to use command, it is `\pgfmathsign{<num>}`. See the [PGF manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf), sec. 95.3, p. 1034.

```
nodes near coords style = {anchor={sign(\myy)*90*(-1)}},
```

[image]

Full simplified example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{xfp}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\int_new:N \l_bjprim_round_int

\keys_define:nn {bjprim}
  {
    positions-after-comma .int_set:N = \l_bjprim_round_int
  }

\NewDocumentCommand \percentage { O{} m }
  {
    \keys_set:nn {bjprim}{positions-after-comma=2, #1}
    \fpeval{round(#2*100, \l_bjprim_round_int)}\%
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        ybar,
        enlargelimits=1,
        legend style={
          at={(0.5,-0.15)},
          anchor=north,
          legend columns=-1
        },
        ylabel={Rendement op geïnvesteerd vermogen},
        yticklabel ={%
          \pgfmathparse{\tick*100}\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}\,\%
        },
        symbolic x coords={Vorig jaar,Huidig jaar},
        xtick=data,
        point meta = explicit symbolic ,
        visualization depends on=y \as \myy,
        nodes near coords,
        nodes near coords style = {anchor={sign(\myy)*90*(-1)}},
        bar width = 1.5cm,
        ymajorgrids =true,
      ]
      \addplot[fill,color=red] coordinates {
        (Vorig jaar,0.05)   [0.05]
        (Huidig jaar,-0.05) [-0.05]
      };
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks it works!